# Limit log size with existing logging library (C++)

Tags: c++

Being a beginner in C++, I found myself facing a problem when attempting to limit log file size using the ezlogger library: http://axter.com/ezlogger/

My take at it was to:
1) check log file size every n seconds
2) if size is too big, start logging to a second file (clearing it beforehand) Then switch between the files every n seconds.

I did 1. And I tackled 2 by changing the symlink used by the logging library as logging output file location (the app is running on Linux). However, it seems that the library retains a reference to the original file and never starts logging to the new file after changing the link.

The reason I decided to go this way was because I didn't want to touch the library. For an experienced programmer it would probably make more sense to somehow modify the library to enable switching log files. But with all the static variables and methods and hpp files containing actual code, I couldn't make sense of it and didn't know where to start.

So I guess I'm looking for opinions on my current approach, help with getting it to work and/or advice on how to do it differently/better.

Thanks.

Edit: I'm working on an existing older project which already uses ezlogger so I'd like to avoid using a different library if possible.

Comment: use `logrotate`?

Comment: Given that the website seems to have not changed since 2006, I'd advise you to use some more modern logging library, e.g. Boost.Log or etc. C++ has changed a lot since 2006.

Comment: why not use better library like log4cpp and use its log4cpp::RollingFileAppender

Comment: Probably should have mentioned that I'm using ezlogger because I'm working on an existing project which uses it. Not sure exactly when it was written but it definitely is a few years old. Thanks for the suggestions though. If the solution can't be achieved using ezlogger, I will definitely have a look at using something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use logrotate (if you use unix like system) as it was suggested or modify your logging library. Those static variable you mention appear to be located in [get_log_stream()](http://axter.com/ezlogger/ezlogger__output__policy_8hpp-source.htm). The modification would require checking on each get_log_stream call, the size of the current logging file. If the size exceeds some number of bytes then reopen stream. I don't see this logging library to be thread safe, so it probably isn't so you don't have to worry about it. But if your application is multithreaded then make a note of it.

The modification of `get_log_stream` would look as follows (its pseudocode):

```
// ...    

if (logfile_is_open) {
    if (logfile.tellp() > 1024*1024*10 /*10MB*/) {
        logfile.close();
        logfile.clear(); //clears flags
        // TODO: update FileName accordingly, ie. add a count to it.
        // TODO: remove older log files, etc.
        logfile.open(FileName.c_str(), std::ios_base::out);
    }
}

// Below is old code.

if (logfile_is_open) return logfile;
return std::cout;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you think checking for size on every log entry will not add too much overhead? Especially when file is big? If I understand this right, the file is already open and its length/position of last character is already known so this shouldn't be an issue. Am I right?

Comment: It might be inefficient but you dont have to call it on each get_log_stream execution.